# DSolve for System of Non-Homogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Solve:
x' = Ax + b
Given:
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
b = {{e^{t}},{2}};

This will solve if b == 0

```
DSolve[{x1'[t], x2'[t]} == a.{x1[t], x2[t]}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]
```

But if I add "b" I get "DSolve::nolist: ...there should be no lists on either side of the equation" error.

```
DSolve[{x1'[t], x2'[t]} == a.{x1[t], x2[t]}+b, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Could it be that your variable name is a capital `A` and you `DSolve` code has a lower case `a`? For instance `DSolve[{x1'[t], x2'[t]} == A.{x1[t], x2[t]} + b, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]` works for me.

Comment: Also, generally I avoid starting variable names with capitals so as not to conflict with built-in functions and variables. See #4 in mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
b = {E^t, 2};
X = {x1[t], x2[t]};
cinits = Thread[(X /. {t -> 0}) == {1, 2}];
DSolve[{D[X, t] == A.X + b, cinits}, X, t]
```

Comment: Why does this work as opposed to what I have? And how would you add initial condition into the DSolve[Thread that you have? Say we have x0[t] = 1 and x1[t] = 2? Thanks!

Comment: There are some syntax  rules regarding lists handling...

Comment: @Mathhelp Note that `DSolve[{D[X, t] == A.X + b, cinits}, X, t]` works without `Thread`.

Comment: Yes. It is now fixed. Thanks.